# Is there a way to execute code in JavaScript by only referencing it?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I stumbled upon code like this

```
if (options.callback) 
    { options.callback; }
```

This can't be right, correct? Options is some object with an attribute titled 'callback', now to execute callback it would require a options.callback(); Or is there some way to perform the callback if it is an object's attribute somehow?

If the code above is correct, what should I add in the callback property to make it execute?

Comment: Adding `()` to you callback. A function is an object in JavaScript, and it has two methods for application `.apply` and `.call`

Comment: Yes, so this must be a bug in the production code. I cant see how options.callback would execute anything no matter what callback is.

Comment: Correct; it would do nothing as-is. It's like saying `42;`.

Comment: Unless it is a getter, but then it is executed twice.

Comment: @Antonioo Unless it is a getter (and I doubt it), then it is a bug, because it does nothing.

Comment: Sure so @some, Ive fixed the bug. Confirmed, but I dont know which answer I should mark as accepted, all of you where very helpful in helping me understand this. Thanks

Comment: I added an answer and marked it as community wiki, so I don't get any reputation from it. Feel free to mark it as accepted so this question get the status of answered. (the answer from Philipp isn't the correct answer to our problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a bug, since it doesn't do anything useful.

The only way it could do anything was if `callback` was a getter, but then it would be called twice and that doesn't make any sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the callback function was defined as a getter method:

```
options.__defindeGetter__("callback", function() {
    // code of callback routine
}
```

so the function gets executed when the value callback is requested. Note that `__defineGetter__` is a non-standard extension and also marked as deprecated by MDN, so it should generally not be used.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter

Comment: There is a standardized way in ECMAScript262:5, 15.2.3.6 Object.defineProperty and variants.

Comment: Hmm interesting, though this is not the case here, dont see it anywhere.